# BigCommerce Stencil Theme: Access store email

Tags: bigcommerce

`{{settings.phone_number}}` will return the phone number from `https://store-xxx.mybigcommerce.com/manage/settings/store-profile` in stencil

Similarly; How can i get the store email address in Stencil? `{{settings.email}}` did not work. And i dont see any mention in the docs. The value i want in the theme was set on this page `https://store-xxx.mybigcommerce.com/manage/settings/store-profile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The store profile email isn't available as a {{settings}} property on the storefront, but it is accessible through the Store Information API:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store/store-information-api/store-information-reference/getstore

The store profile email address is the "from" address on transactional emails that are sent out from the store. It's not necessarily the publicly visible customer service email, unlike the Administrator's email under Misc. Store settings, which appears on the order confirmation page. Both the profile email and the admin email can be pulled through the Store Info API.

Could I ask: Is the goal to have a handlebars expression that can pull the customer service email address dynamically and display it on the storefront without hardcoding, or did you plan to use it in a different way?

Comment: We are facing same issue at the moment. We may hard-code or add the email to theme settings (`config.json`) or language file (`en.json`), but we will definitely not be doing an API call for this... Why not make it available at `settings`, as `email_address`, just like `phone_number`? (This is a rethorical question.)

Comment: @J.Bruni We've discussed it, but we're concerned that it would be easy to scrape and might have the potential to be misused. Curious to hear your thoughts on that. We've also talked about exposing the settings email address in the Storefront Orders API as another approach.